Remove the extra space on the first page within the printing area
I have two simple questions. I want to print a page with these contents. The printing area for the first page is like this.

and for the second page

My first question is: As you see, the first page has a different distance from the top than the second page (and other pages). However, I don't want this difference; I want the exact same distance.
And my second question is: Is there any way to show the print date and time only on the first page?
this is my css and js code


  window.print();
@media print {
  /* Hides the entire body content initially */
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; /* Ensure colors appear correctly when printing */
  }

  /* Shows only the specified element and keeps other elements hidden */
  #ride-receipts {
    visibility: visible; /* Makes it visible */
    gap: 60px; /* Adds the specified gap */
    width: 100%; /* Sets the full width */
  }

  #ride-receipts > div {
    break-inside: avoid;
  }

  .drawer {
    display: none;
  }
}

@page {
  size: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}



